# time series classification using neural networks

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series, classification

I want to predict bankruptcy of companies using neural networks. The data set is organized as below:
The research data belongs to 160 companies (50 bankrupt firms and 110 non-bankrupt ones) during time period 2001-2012. Bankruptcy is described by a binary variable (0=healthy, 1=bankrupt). For example, company A is non-bankrupt during 2001-2012, but company B is bankrupted at 2003 there is about 150 features/inputs for each company during each year, so some of these features should be chosen and then the companies’ health condition should be predicted.

Now, I don’t know how to do the classification so as that the extent of similarity within company during years (trend) and between companies would be considered. To put it exactly, I want to consider the trend of change in features during time within the company and between companies.
If my problem is a time series classification, what kind of neural network should I use? Recurrent neural network?If so, how should the data set be organized in Matlab.

```
company         year  Bankruptcy Feature 1 Feature 2 …  …  Feature 150

A              2001    0                              
A                2002    0                              
A                2003    0                              
A                2004    0                              
A                2005    0                              
A                2006    0                              
A                2007    0                              
A                2008    0                              
A                2009    0                              
A                2010    0                              
A                2011    0                              
A                2012    0                              
B                2001    0                              
B                2002    0                              
B                2003    1
```

Best regards,

Comment: I would feed all data of all years per company to the net. So line 1: company A Feature 1 2002 feature 1 2003 ... feature 150 2012. In line 2 the same for company B and so on

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this using neural networks. Given it is a time series, and you have many features, you can consider it as a classification or regression problem. I do not know about your data, I will just example it.

You could feed all data you have in the input layer and provide a ideal output (feature you want to classify) for each sample to train your neural network model. For sample:

```
Company ; Year ; Feature 1 ; Feature 2      Ideal Output
1       ; 2000 ; 1         ; 1              1
2       ; 2001 ; 1         ; 2              0
3       ; 2002 ; 2         ; 4              1
4       ; 2003 ; 5         ; 0              1
5       ; 2004 ; 4         ; 1              0
```

Now, using it as a time series, you could use the forecast window to use it, for smaple, you could select a feature you want to predict and slide a window between the data to estimate the ideal output on the series.

Let's supose you have a time series with these values

```
2.5 ; 2.6 ; 3.2 ; 4.6 ; 5.1 ; 5.2 ; 5.9 ; 6.4 ; 7.1 ; 8.3 ; 9.1
```

Using a forecast window of 3 points, you would have a set like this:

```
Inputs              Ideal Output
2.5 ; 2.6 ; 3.2     4.6
2.6 ; 3.2 ; 4.6     5.1
3.2 ; 4.6 ; 5.1     5.2 
4.6 ; 5.1 ; 5.2     5.9
5.1 ; 5.2 ; 5.9     6.4
5.2 ; 5.9 ; 6.4     7.1 
5.9 ; 6.4 ; 7.1     8.3 
6.4 ; 7.1 ; 8.3     9.1
```

Another way is to use a slide window using more properties, for sample, `Company`, `Year`, `Feature 1`, etc.. but you will get a big neural network model. It is not a problem, but can take more computation time to train it.

Another important point, neural network is a mathematical model, so, qualitative properties such as `Company` where you have values as `A` or `B` have to be converted to numbers, for sample: `1` (for `A`), `2` (for `B`), etc..

Comment: thanks, but my ideal outputs is a binary variable (1 or 0) which means the company is bankrupted or not, so it is classification.

Comment: No problem related with it, just organize your set as a classification problem. The data on this post is just to exemplify how to do it.

Comment: @toddmo -- I think this problem is somehow similar to the following link and it should be solved by recurrent neural network, but I don't know how (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137721/neural-network-classification-from-time-series).

Comment: @Paolo Zaia --I would be appreciated if you could apply your suggested edit because I cannot do that.